# how to upgrade from magento 2.3.x to 2.4.x

Tags: magento2

how to upgrade from magento 2.3.x to 2.4.x

Comment: Hi there please follow this link - https://www.mgt-commerce.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-3-to-2-4/

Comment: thanks for the answer yar , life saver

Answer (score 0):

Before start magento upgrade you need to check magento system requirements and update first if required **Like :-** (php, composer, mysql, elastic search) version etc then start work on it.

You can upgrade magento version using command line for that you need to follow some steps which i have given below.

1. First Enable maintenance mode using a command.
   ==> **php bin/magento maintenance:enable**
2. Take backup of you composer.json file using command.
   ==> **cp composer.json composer.json.bak**
3. Update composer.json file
   ==> **composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.5 --no-update**
4. Composer update
   ==> **composer update**
5. Please run below commands one by one.
   **php bin/magento cache:clean**
   **rm -rf var/cache/***

   **rm -rf var/page_cache/***

   **rm -rf generated/code/***

   **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

   **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

   **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**
6. Disable Maintainance Mode.
   ==> **php bin/magento maintenance:disable**